# Load data from dictionary in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

Hello I've got combobox in WPF

```
<ComboBox Name="mcombo" SelectedValuePath="Key" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dictionary}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

also behind i have

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("val", "valvalval");
```

What I forget? In combobox, no data!

Comment: datacontext is set correct
?

Comment: how to make datacontex?

Answer (score 0):

First of all dictionary should be property not variable.

then You should bind Dictionary to ItemsSource

```
<ComboBox Name="mcombo" SelectedValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding Dictionary}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" /> /Dont bind dictionary here. makes no sense
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

hope this helps..

Thanks

Comment: when i add:mcombo.datacontext = dictionary;

Comment: my program give error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: use mcombo.ItemsSource= dictionary;(but then you dont need binding aymore).  If you want to use mvvm, then you have to make property of dictionary type, not a variable.

Comment: if you are doing mcombo.datacontext = dictionary, which ideally you should not, you will have to update the ItemsSource binding to just ItemsSource="{Binding}". See if this works for u. And if possible can you post the exception you are getting